# TryGetValue with splitwords

Tags: c#, dictionary, split

Hi there I had a look about before posting and couldn't really figure out how to do this so I was wondering if anyone could help.

Basically, my code just now works like, if I enter a word in the text box and then click a button, it displays the split word from my dictionary in text box 2.

For example, if my dictionary file contains **black, white** and I enter black into text box 1 and then click a button, white displays in text box 2. 
...you get me?

So anyway, I'm trying to get it so if I enter a line of text in text box 1 it'll copy that line of text into text box 2 and change the word. So

"my chair has a black cushion" would translate to "my chair has a white cushion"

```
private void btnTrans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    string outputString = null;
    if (d.TryGetValue(inputBx.Text, out outputString))      
    {                            
        outputBx.Text = inputBx.Text + outputString;   
    }
    else    
    {                
        outputBx.Text = "Unknown";        
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how i'd go about editing that to fit my needs, so any help?

Comment: Change only one word? What if you have multiples? Should `white` change to `black` and `black` to `white`?

Comment: Oops yeah if may have multiples. and no only a one way switch because they're seperated by a comma in the dictionary. black, white green,blue and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var repStr = txtBox.Text;

foreach (var kvp in d)
{
    repStr = repStr.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

txtBox2.Text = repStr;
```

You will probably want to replace kvp.Key with spaces on left and right to kvp.Value with spaces on left and right, to ensure you don't replace parts of words, or you can ensure the dictionary's keys and values are all padded with spaces on left and right.

With dictionary:
{"White", "Black"}
{"Black", "White"}

There will be a problem if the sentence contains both white and black.

An alternative would be [Jetti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926031/1282539).

Comment: If you want to do it using string.Split, then split in spaces and for each word in the resulting array, TryGetValue from d, and replace if found. But that is just going around and around for nothing (and also less efficient)

Comment: It should be fine because my dictionary words actually are all CAPS. so it works. However, how would I go about combining the error message etc to that?

Comment: I don't see why any error message should be produced, but if you would like to inform the user that not a single word has changed, simply compare txtBox.Text with repStr after the loop to see if anything has changed, or have a bool initialized as false, and set it to true in the loop, and check for it's value at the end.

Comment: Yeah I see, you're actually right there. Thanks for all the help. Kudos

Comment: How about a piece of code that would change only the dictionary words found to a different colour?

Comment: You mean mark the replaced words in the result with some color (in a rich textbox)?

Comment: Yeah in the rich textbox. Something like Color Red = Color.FromName(repStr); ?

Comment: Post this is a new question, so others can enjoy the answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = txtBox.Text;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["black"] = "white";
dict["white"] = "black";
string[] chunks = test.Split(' ');
foreach (string s in chunks)
{
  string val;
  if (dict.TryGetValue(s, out val))
  {
    sb.Append(val);
    sb.Append(" ");
  }
  else
  {
    sb.Append(s);
    sb.Append(" ");
  }
}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
```

There is a little more in there than is needed (such as adding the spaces and then trimming when you could figure out in the loop if it is at the end or not) but this is definitely enough to get your started and you can start optimizing if you need to. Note: I added the dictionary just for my own testing to make sure it worked (which it does).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to play around with the answers to make sure I fully understand it.

Comment: @user1300788 you're welcome, it isn't as concise as [Yorye Nathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9925873/509746) but it will for sure match only the words that are keys and you won't have partial matches.

Comment: This might go over the same words twice in the dictionary, which is a shame. To ensure my answer will not match partial words, I suggested padding with spaces at left and right.

Comment: But then again, turns out my answer has it's problems too. We're linking each other now :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan I'm not sure what you mean by "go over the same words twice". It iterates over each word and then checks if it is in the dictionary and then moves on, adding the word to the StringBuilder. It will only replace what it sees and has no knowledge of what is ahead or behind (in its current state) meaning that it won't double duplicate or get tricked up no matter how many dictionary words there are.

Comment: Yes, I meant that in case of the sentence "Hi, I'm white and I like the color white", it will TryGetValue of "white" twice. But eh, it doesn't really matter. Your answer is actually better (though you can tidy it up and make it look nicer and more readable)

Comment: @YoryeNathan ah I gotcha. I was under the impression that it was supposed to flip it each time it sees it. If that is wrong I can easily modify it so that it checks to see that a key has been used.

Comment: If you need to flip the values each time seen, my answer would have no problem :P But it's probably not it. There isn't much logic to just flip words to the user.

Comment: @YoryeNathan according to the comment the OP made on the original question, it may contain multiples.

Comment: Using the way @YoryeNathan said I have got it to work, however I still can't figure out how to change the colour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926912/changing-string-colour
Any more help would be GREATLY appreciated guys. Sorry, i'm a bit of a beginner :L