# Changing string colour

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, colors, richtextbox

Okay, so this is a carry on from my last question, but I have the code:

```
private void btnTrans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
    {
        var abrvStr = inputBx.Text;

        foreach (var kvp in d)

        {
            abrvStr = abrvStr.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

        }

        outputBx.Text = abrvStr;


    }
```

Basically it's part of a dictionary program, so that when you enter a line of text in textbox 1 it appears in textbox 2 with a word replaced from textbox 1 in the dicitonary. 
So if black,white is in the dictionary and I enter The wall is black. The wall is white will appear in textbox 2. So all's good.

Right now the tricky part, how would I alter that to allow me have the changed word in textbox 2 as the colour red. So in my above example, the wall is **white**. White would be red in the output line of text.

Note, I am using RichTextBoxes

**C# Language!**

Comment: Doh! c# Sorry sorry i'll edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on [Oliver Jacot-Descombes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927218/509746):

```
private void btnTrans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    var abrvStr = inputBx.Text;

    foreach (var kvp in d)

    {            
        abrvStr = abrvStr.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        int start = abrvStr.IndexOf(kvp.Value);
        if(start >= 0) 
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = abrvStr;
            richTextBox1.Select(start, kvp.Value.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use a switch statement on the value of the dictionary to get what color you want to change the selection. You will need to modify that to fit the values in your dictionary as well as what colors you want.

Comment: @user1300788 fixed it. -1 means that the value isn't in the string. We just have to make a check to ensure that the value exists before we do anything

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. It runs fine but doesn't change the word red

Comment: @user1300788 check the edit again, I added a line where you add the text to the richtextbox. I left that out before but it is needed and doesn't complete this example without it. I tested this code and it works for me. Although I just noticed it only will do one color and not the rest.

Comment: No idea why this isn't working for me. I'm using two richtextboxs and i'm changing your code for that need. But I can't see why it doesn't just change the "changed" string in the text to a different colour

Comment: @user1300788 can you post your code to a site like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and I'll take a look and see if I see a problem?

Comment: @user1300788 are you sure that "red" or "green" are values in the dictionary? Also, are they lower case or upper case?

Comment: That's what i was doing wrong. Instead of red or green, how would I change that to any dictionary value entered? abrvStr maybe?

Comment: @user1300788 the best way to do it is the way I have it. Make a switch based on the colors that are possible and then change the color that way. The reason for this is because if the value in the dictionary isn't formatted correctly it won't register a color properly when converting from a string using the FromName() method

Comment: I think I've confused you what I was wanting, basically I just want ANY dictionary value to be a different colour from the rest of the text. My dicitonary file that I load has lots of different words in it so I can't do that.

Comment: This now works! thanks. It doesn't work for multiple dictionary words though but I'll try to sort that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SelectionColor` property of the `RichTextBox`. Start by selecting the word that you want to format

```
string word = "white";
int start = richTextBox1.Find(word);
if (start >= 0) {
    richTextBox1.Select(start, word.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Useful thanks! I must apologise because I am a beginner. Where you have start, length. What would I change those to?

Comment: `start` is the starting position of your word. `length` is its length. Please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a the reference to the KVP in the dictionary to the Textbox's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property. When the user changes the color, get the KVP from the Tag property and change the value in the KVP. I provide insight to the Tag property on my blog C[# Winforms and the Hidden Association Tag](http://omegacoder.com/?p=66). WPF/Silverlight also use the Tag property on controls as well..

--- Edit per user request ---

I am not sure why you need to enumerate a dictionary. The whole point of a dictionary is to quickly get the key. My example uses that and does not do the for loop.

... The initialization location....

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, System.Drawing.Color>>()
{
        { "Black", new Tuple<string,System.Drawing.Color>("White", Color.Green) },
        { "White", new Tuple<string,System.Drawing.Color>("Black", Color.Red) }

};
```

... (later in code)...

private void btnTrans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
var key = inputBx.Text; // Let us say "White"

if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{

    var targetColor = myDictionary[key]; // Just get the value

    outputBx.Select(0, targetColor.Item1.Length);
    outputBx.SelectionColor = targetColor.Item2;
    outputBx.Text = targetColor.Item1;
}
else
{
    outputBx.Text = "Unknown";
}
```

}

Check out my blog article on dictionaries for more info [C# Dictionary Tricks](http://omegacoder.com/?p=188)

Comment: The user doesn't change the colour though. I meant so that it shows the changed word in textbox 2 in a different colour to the rest

Comment: Understood. Have the KVP value be a Tuple<string,color> instead of just text. Then when the textbox is loaded, get item1 for the text and item2 for the target color.

Comment: any chance you could give me an example in your answer of what that code would look like. I'm not sure where i'd alter it about on my code

Comment: Which topic? Tuple? RichTextbox? Dynamic loading? Data Binding?

Comment: Just where i'd change it to <string,color> instead of <string,string> I'm not sure where i'd put that in the above code